# Loads of 3075 errors on Access SQL connection update to ODBC native driver 11

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

Recently I updated the SQL server connection string  to ODBC native driver 11.0 (it used to be 10.0). At one of my clients (Company B), and also at my computer locally this works fine, but at one client (Company A) I am getting multiple weird errors.

At first I noticed the error when opening a report, I was absolutely clueless where the error came from because at my own computer it worked fine (accdb) but at Company A it didn't. The only real difference was that they run the application on a Access Runtime. So I also tested it at Company B which also runs the application on the runtime and there it worked fine..

So after a lot of research I found this article:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28206732/Possible-issue-with-MS-Access-RUNTIME.html

In this article someone mentioned that the error could be related to the odbc driver, and it happens to be that after I updated the ODBC drivers these errors popped up, while it all worked fine with the ODBC 10 driver. In the Article they also mention that the error could be caused by a filter on the report (when opening). So I removed the filter (it was a useless filter anyway) and it worked again!

Now the error returned on several other reports and removing the filter on these reports is not an option (the errors all seem to have something to do with filters on the report). 
The error numbers are the same (3075) but the error description varies. One error has the following error: `This function is not available in expressions, in query-expression iif(isnull([Field1],[Field2]-Date(),[Field2]-[Field1].`
The other error is: `This function is not available in expressions, in query-expression FORMAT(Min[tblX.FieldX]),'hh:mm:ss'.`

I compared the SQL Server Native Client versions of my own system, the system of Company B where it works fine and the system of Company A where it doesn't work and they all have the same version - `03.80` (I installed 11.0 besides the 10.0 and the 10.0 also have the same ver. numbers).

My Access frontend application uses linked SQL server tables using `ADODB / CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append` 
The connection string is as follows:

```
DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;SERVER=***;DATABASE=***;UID=***;PWD=***;regional=no;Application Name=xxx;MARS_Connection=yes;
```

**Some other additional information that might be related to the problem:**

- The company on which it doesn't work uses a VPS (Virtual Private Server) where each user logs on to. The Native client is installed once on the VPS while the Native client for the other company (where it does work) is installed on every computer where they use the application (because they don't work with a VPS).
- At Company B (where it works) I manually installed the Native Driver, I download the install file from this website: https://accessexperts.com/blog/2015/08/23/use-sql-server-native-client-11-0-for-the-best-performance/, at the company where it doesn't work the Native Driver 11.0 was already installed (no history where it came from).

Anyone has a clue how to fix this problem? Thanks you in advance!

**UPDATE** 
I found the solution myself. Check the post below.

Answer (score 1):

For all the unlucky people that spend hours and hours debugging and research, like me, on this issue, I found the solution.

After trying multiple things (which all didn't work) like installing a new ODBC 11 native driver, removing filters, copying Access queries to a view and linking the view in Access as a table, checking and changing language settings, etc., etc., I finally came across a post which stated that it might had to do something with the References.

So I checked the application for broken references and when I did the Access application gave me an error that one object library was not registered. Unfortunately, I couldn't exactly pin out which reference it was since the error would pop-up on different references each time I moved a random reference up or down (in priority), it almost seemed index related.

Finally after removing 2 references and making them `Late Binding`, which I actually picked randomly to test, all the weird errors disappeared...
So for some reason one of those 2 references were broken at Company A (see main post).

Conclusion: Use as much late bindings as you can cause those reference can give you a lot of problems while not knowing where they are coming from.

Comment: Thanks for sharing - #1 post on the internet for broken Access applications is due to those failing to check references - your post and follow is another confirmation of this common issue of missing or broken references. And thumbs up for suggesting late binding as again this can solve many  a problem like this.